# How to customize redirecting http to https on IIS8.5

Tags: iis, https, iis-8.5

I need to redirect http to https on external network (internet), but on local network such as 192.168.1.100 works on http. I used this following configuration:

```
<system.webServer> 
<rewrite> 
<rules> 
<rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> 
<match url="(.*)" /> 
<conditions> 
<add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" /> 
</conditions> 
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule> 
</rules> 
</rewrite> 
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: By "local network such as 192.168.1.100" do you mean, when are you accessing a website by this IP? Like: `http://192.168.1.100`

Comment: @VictorLeontyev that's right. IIS should work on http when users call server locally and work on https when call over internet by domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an additional condition "host shouldn't match 192.168.1.100".

Your rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true"> 
    <match url="(.*)" /> 
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^192.168.1.100$" negate="true" /> 
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
</rule>
```